# Executing a command when a list is equal to one line of a matrix in python

Tags: python, list, matrix

If all 3 of the values in the list below are equal to any of the 3 values in one line of the matrix, I want it to print 'hello'.

```
#if x is equal to the 1st line of the matrix I want it to print hello. If x is equal to the 2nd part and not the 1st I still want it to print the same string.

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [7, 8, 9]
]
if x == (y):
    print('hello')
```

As shown above, the x list value is equal to one of the lines in the matrix but it won't print hello. How would I get the program to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the normal case, you can simply use -

```
if x in y:
    print('hello')
```

If you want to check your only values in any order then you need to sort first as shown below.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [
[1, 3, 2],
[4, 5, 6],
[3, 4, 5],
[7, 8, 9]
]
x = sorted(x)
for i in range(len(y)):
    y[i] = sorted(y[i])
if x in y:
    print('hello')
```

Comment: OP didn't say anything about the order of elements, so there's no reason to assume sorting is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison you're making - `x == (y)` fails, because `(y)` evaluates to `y`, and `x == y` is False (as `y` is a nested list).

What you want to do is iterate over the lines:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [7, 8, 9]
]

for yi in y:
    if x == yi:
        print("Hello")
```

For the given input this prints Hello once. If `[1,2,3]` appears multiple times, it prints Hello every time it finds one.

Note that this assumes that `[1,2,3] != [3,2,1]` (which is what Python assumes internally). You have to tweak it if order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in function for this kind of testing, called `any`, that checks if any of a sequence of values is True. We don't have the true or false values we want yet, so we need to create them. The strategy is to transform from the value that's `in` the `y` list, into a true value that indicates whether that value is equal to `x`. We can do this elegantly with a generator expression:

```
any(row == x for row in y)
```

It means exactly what it sounds like: if `any` of the `row` values is `== x`, considered `for` the `row` values that are `in y`.